# Convergence in $L^2$ norm given inner product converges

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Suppose $(f_n)$ and $f$ are in $L^2$ and $\int_E f_ng \rightarrow \int_E fg,\,$ for $g \in L^2(E)$. If $\|\,f_n\|_2 \rightarrow \|\,f\|_2$, then show that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^2$. (All functions are real valued).

I think that I have to add and substract something inside $\|\,f_n-f\|_2$ and use some inequality (Holder's/Triangular) and someway make the inner product $(f_n,g)$ appear but I still haven't found a way. Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(a+b)^2= \cdots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\langle\, f,g\rangle=\int_E fg\,d\mu$.

We have that
$$
\|\,f_n-f\|^2=\langle\, f_n-f,f_n-f\rangle=\langle\, f_n,f_n\rangle-2\langle\, f_n,f\rangle+\langle\,f,f\rangle.
$$
Hence, as $\langle\, f_n,f\rangle\to \langle\, f,f\rangle$, we have that if 
$\langle\, f_n,f_n\rangle\to\langle\, f,f\rangle$, then $\|\,f_n-f\|\to 0$.